# show L: $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ is defined by $x \mapsto Ax$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i'm not sure how to start this problem.

$x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

a map $L: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ is defined by $x \mapsto Ax$.

using the definition of $Ax$, i have to show this map is linear.

i have been able to do this for other types of objects, but i haven't been able to find any examples for this.

my usual strategy is to show $L(cx + y) = c \cdot L(x) + L(y)$, but i can't figure out how to define $cx + y$ or even how to calculate $L(y)$ here.

edit: i've tried showing linearity based on the comments i received. i am implementing the approach introduced by my text and lectures.

c is in the field F.

L(cx + y) = A(cx + y)
          = A * (cx) + Ay
          = c * Ax + Ay

c * L(x) + L(y) = c * Ax + Ay

since L(cx + y) = c * L(x) + L(y), L is linear.

Comment: this is an elementary exercise, but you need a firm grasp of the concept of ''matrix multiplication'' in order to solve it. Do you know how matrix multiplication is defined, rigorously and explicitly? (this will in particular apply to the multiplication between a matrix and a so-called column vector)

Comment: i was given the definition of Ax a while ago, but we haven't gone into much depth with it yet. from what i do understand about it, the product of a matrix and a column vector will be another matrix with as many rows as the original matrix and as many columns as there are entries in the column vector.

Comment: leaving aside the deeper aspects of matrix multiplication, if you at least have a proper and explicit definition of matrix multiplication at hand, then you should try to show straight from the definition that: $M(N+P)=MN+MP$ for any matrices $M$ of type $(m,n)$ respectively $N,P$ of type $(n,p)$ over an arbitrary ring $A$ and also that $\lambda(MN)=(\lambda M)N=M(\lambda N)$ for any matrices $M$ of type $(m,n)$, $N$ of type $(n,p)$ over arbitrary **commutative** ring $A$ and for any scalar $\lambda \in A$ (in your particular case the ring in question will be none other than the field of reals)

Comment: What do you mean "define $cx+y$"? You're supposed to show that the property holds for all scalars $c$ and all vectors $x$ and $y$. And regarding calculating $L(y)$, it's just $Ay$ (obviously, since that's what the definition of $L$ says).

Comment: thank you for your helpful comments. i was a little confused by some of the terminology (i think rings is a topic in the next course i'm going to take) but i've done my best to implement your feedback.

Comment: By the way in the future you can type pretty math with Mathjax, a tutorial is here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference